# What is the probability of player A winning this Coin Toss Game?

Tags: probability, statistics

Player A throws a fair coin n+1 times. Player B throws the same coin n times. Player A wins if she throws more heads than Player B. What is the probability of player A winning the game?

My approach has been that since the answer is independent of n, so I chose n=1. So, A can win 3 out 8 times (assuming that Head-Tail is same as Tail-Head) hence the probability is 3/8. Is my assumption correct? What about the approach? How can the solution be generalized?

Comment: "*Assuming that Head-Tail is same as Tail-Head*"  Why do you say that?  If you wish to find probabilities by counting, then you must recognize *what* you are counting.  We took a ratio over $8$.  Those $8$ things that we took a ratio of are the *ordered* ways in which three coin flips can occur.  The order matters in such a scenario so we may *not* just say "head-tail is same as tail-head."  There are *four* ways out of the eight equally likely ways in which $A$ wins, not three.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh yes. Thank you!